# ECONNREFUSED when starting node express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4562
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
```

here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var net = require('net');
var app = express();
var i = 0;
app.get('/', function (req, res) 
{
    i = i+1; //no of clinets request gin ne ki liye
    console.log(i + "fa..sa");
    var client = net.connect({port: 4562},"192.168.202.101", function() {  
        console.log('connected to server!'); });
    client.write("Ho gaya bhai");
    client.end();
    res.send('ho gaya bhai..');
});

app.listen(6544);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your error message you have an error in the way you call `net.connect`. It looks like you want to connect to `192.168.202.101:4562`, but you try to connect to ´127.0.0.1:4562´. Try either:

```
net.connect({ port: 4562, host: "192.168.202.101"}, function(){});
```

or:

```
net.connect(4562, "192.168.202.101", function() {});
```

Comment: thank you for answer but it is giving again the same error.

Comment: No. It will give another answer. Possibly `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.202.101:4562`. It that case there is nothing running on that server/port.

Comment: thanks it worked . i was running old file while i have updated the new file that's why it was not working. Thanks again

Comment: here's a package that will watch for file changes and re-run the file. https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon